# Port change of a service is causing other service to not browse

Tags: wcf

I got two IIS services in my machine, which are using port 443. Both the services are not able to start in parallel. I tried changing the port of one of the service from 443 to 8080. Now I am able to start both the services and the modified service is browsing properly. The issue is not the service which I did not modify is starting but not browsing. On browsing service is giving page not found error. I did reset iis after making the changes. Could any one please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I did some hit and try and got the fix. When  I am  modifying the binding port in one iis site the that service is working fine. But this action of changing binding port on one service is effecting the other service which was sharing the same port previously. For unmodified service not sure why automatically the Ssl certificate is getting changed to "not selected". 
I selected the sll for the service I was not will to modify and service started working.

Steps:
1) iis site x and y using same binding port 443.
2) on starting both the sites in parallel iis throwing error "this website cannot be started another website may be using this port". One site at a time works properly.
3) Changed the binding port for x
4) x and y starting properly.
5) x browsing and y not browsing its throwing error - page not found
6) action in step 3 caused automatic change in ssl certificate for y. Ssl certificate got changed to not selected
7) Selected the ssl certificate for y
8) every thing is working fine now